How do I expose information from Django model to the forms/views(?)/html(?) to be able to see all information built-in the model
I am trying to add more information to a form dropdown built using Django forms. A basic explanation of the program is:

The user logs in
The user can create 'decks' that are to be displayed on the 'game_tracking' page
The user goes to the 'game_tracking' page, and the first dropdown loads all of the names of decks that the user created as well as the additional info from the model 'Deck' of if it is/isn't a cEDH deck.

I am unsure of how to expose whether the deck's information of is_cedh, in addition to the name, in the dropdown
This is what it currently shows when I expand the dropdown
This, ideally, is what I am attempting to do.
Thanks in advance for taking the time to read/answer. I have been working on this for longer than I would like to admit...
This is my models.py file.
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True,
                                blank=True,
                                default='Default.png',
                                upload_to='images/')

    user = models.ForeignKey(User,
                         max_length=10,
                         on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                         null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)


class Deck(models.Model):
    deck = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    is_cedh = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User,
                         max_length=10,
                         on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                         null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.deck)


class Game(models.Model):
    NUM_PLAYERS_CHOICE = [
        (2, 2),
        (3, 3),
        (4, 4),
        (5, 5),
        (6, 6)
        ]

    OUTCOME_CHOICE = [
        ('Win', 'Win'),
        ('Loss', 'Loss'),
        ('Draw', 'Draw'),
        ('Incomplete', 'Incomplete'),
        ]

    # ForeignKeys
    deck = models.ForeignKey(Deck, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    wincon = models.ForeignKey(Wincon, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    num_players = models.IntegerField(choices=NUM_PLAYERS_CHOICE, default=4)
    outcome = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=OUTCOME_CHOICE, default='Win')

Here is my forms.py file
class GameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GameForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['deck'].queryset = Deck.objects.filter(user=user)

class Meta:
    model = Game
    exclude = {'date', 'time', }
    labels = {
        'deck': 'What deck',
        'num_players': '# of Players',
        'outcome': 'Outcome',
    },

This is my views.py
@login_required(login_url='my-login')
def game_tracker(request):
    user_decks = Deck.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = GameForm(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = GameForm(request.user)

    context = {'form': form, }
    return render(request, 'gametracker_app/gametracker.html', context=context)

And this is my HTML.
{% block content %}
    <form action=""
          method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="container-sm p-4">
        <div class="card"
             style="">
          <div class="card-body">
            {{ form.deck|as_crispy_field }}
            <br>
            <a href="{% url 'my-decks' %}"
               class="">
              <p class="">Add new deck?</p>
            </a>
            <div class="flex-container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm">
                  {{ form.num_players|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                  {{ form.outcome|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <button type='submit'
                    class="btn btn-secondary">Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}


The deck name/value pairs are coming from the queryset generated in this line:
self.fields['deck'].queryset = Deck.objects.filter(user=user)

You can intercept these values and add what you need. However, it appears that deviating from the queryset means you need to alter the choices attribute of the field with a generated 2-tuple, rather than replace the queryset directly
user_decks = Deck.objects.filter(user=user)
user_decks_list = []
for deck in user_decks:
    if deck.is_cedh:
         deck.deck += ":isCEDH"
    user_deck_list.append((deck.id, deck.deck))
self.fields['deck'].choices = user_decks_list

Another method might be to override the modelfield itself, as documented in the docs
To paraphrase that example:
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField

class MyModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        if self.is_cedh:
            return super().label_from_instance() + ":cedh"
        return super().label_from_instance()

And make sure you update the model field type to MyModelChoiceField

I removed the self.fields['deck'].queryset = Deck.objects.filter(user=user) and added your change, but nothing changes. Your answer makes sense but it doesn't alter the text like expected.

Edited in a fix
